# rbenv not switching Ruby versions correctly

Tags: ruby, vagrant, rbenv

After following the setup described on the Github page for `rbenv` and running the `rbenv global 1.9.2-p290` command, `ruby -v` still outputs 1.8.7. When I try and run bundle, it errors because of the new Ruby 1.9 hash syntax, so I know that it is still running with Ruby 1.8.

I ran into this problem following the Vagrant Railscast. So this is in a Vagrant virtual box as in the episode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, this happened to me once when I had a stray `.rbenv-version` file lying around. Did you maybe create one by accident with `rbenv local` before? Or does the project you are trying to run come with one (although that would be strange if it requires 1.9 features).

Comment: I tried messing with rbenv local and it didn't seem to work, but when I restarted my shell the ruby -v showed 1.9.2. I guess you were right about the shell session.

Comment: In that case you probably set it with `rbenv shell`, which sets an environment variable that will disappear once you close the shell session. `rbenv local` would create a `.rbenv-version` file that would still be around.

Answer (score 4):

You have to restart your shell to get it working. Some of the magic in rbenv is contained in your shell's startup script, and unless you invoke the script manually, it will only work in shells started *after* you finish installing.

Another possible cause would be if you skipped the step of adding the code to your shell's startup script.  To fully activate rbenv, you have to add `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` to the appropriate script: `~/.profile` if you're using bash, or `~/.zshrc` if you are using zsh.

Also, if you want to enable `rbenv` for *all* users, you may add them to the system-wide versions of those files, stored in `/etc`